# Protobuf error - found packages main (main.go) and __ (person.pb.go)

Tags: go, protocol-buffers

For my project I am passing data between modules, which were 2 different languages.
So I am trying to learn protobuf.
Followed sample from https://tutorialedge.net/golang/go-protocol-buffer-tutorial/

Everything went well until the last step,

```
Src >go run main.go person.pb.go
found packages main (main.go) and __ (person.pb.go) in src
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You have two packages in the same directory. Rename your person.pb.go package (top of the file) to package main

Answer (score 6):

May be adding `option go_package = "./;main";` in your .proto file will helps.

Comment: For people who are new to Go, can you explain the `./;` syntax?